# Page Elements moving with different screen resolutions

Tags: css, position, element, absolute

This is my site http://lostlegendsmc.net76.net/index.html. Is there any way to keep the absolutely positioned elements from moving when the screen size does. I have already tried to wrap them and that didn't work so I am completely stuck right now

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap everything on a div with hard coded width and height and absolute positioning. If so, your elements will never move, assuming the parent that contains all the content is actually out of the document flow and has always the same size.

Absolute elements are absolute positioned in relation to its parent, so if the parent has an absolute position and a fixed width and height, it prevents its content from being moved as the screen size changes.

Hard coding the size and absolute positioning it is an option: http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/f6zPy/1/

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width:1024px;
    height:1024px;
    position:absolute;
    background:#00f;
}
#one, #two {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
}
#one {
    background:#f00;
    top:300px;
    left:0;
}
#two {
    background:#0f0;
    top:500px;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: I just tried to do that and it completely messed up the page?

Comment: I actually tested your site and it works as you want after you've updated with this solution. What heading are you talking about?

Comment: I fixed the heading but is there any way to edit this so the div will center to the page?

Comment: You need to include the h1 tag in the wrapper div and apply a CSS attribute of text-align:center; to center the text, as it was.